# Ubuntu keeps showing either black screen or display output is not active when using emulation

Tags: display, mac, qcow2

For my pentest course I am required to use an ubuntu vm as my target vm.
my computer environment:
I have a macbook air M1, I am installing it with emulation via UTM as it is a qcow2 file. [System settings for the vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vedlZ.png)

[After selecting to install ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0SMX.png)  I believe it is an issue with the display settings but I have already tried changing it to virtio-ramfb-gl (GPU Supported), virtio-vga, virtio-ramfb etc however it is still showing me the same issue.

How do i go about fixing this? All answers are helpful!!